# Issue with Insert Into due to data types

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run this:

```
INSERT INTO (Col1, Col2, Col3, etc. )
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, etc.
FROM MYTABLE
```

The problem is, that I have some NAs and NULLS in several fields.  I overcame the issue with the INT data type.

```
CONVERT(INT, CASE WHEN IsNumeric([Col1]) = 1 THEN [Col1] ELSE 0 END)
```

I thought the line below would work for decimals, but it doesn't.

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL, CASE WHEN IsNumeric([Col2]) = 1 THEN [Col2] ELSE 0 END)
```

Is there some way around this?  Again, I think it's the NAs and NULLS that's throwing things off.  I am using SQL Server 2018.  Thanks.

Comment: You probably have some bad data in there. IsNumeric is really a horrible function. It should be named something like IsConvertibleToAnyDataTypeThatIsVaguelyANumber. Things like 1e4, $, ¢, and many other things that are not actually numbers will return true from that function.

Comment: Some supporting data for @SeanLange 's comment: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/02/fifteen-things-hate-isnumeric/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `TRY_CONVERT()`!

```
TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL, [Col2])
```

If you want `0` when this fails, add `COALESCE()`:

```
COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL, [Col2]), 0)
```

Comment: @asher - When you use only `DECIMAL` datatype without precision then it will rounding your value. Like 53.53 >> 54, 6.23 >> 6. You can check with my answered query with this `TRY_CONVERT()`.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below select query which will give you only `numeric values` from columns which has ***NULL*** and ***NA*** values.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(COL1) = 1 THEN COL1 ELSE 0 END COL1,
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(COL2) = 1 THEN CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),COL2) ELSE 0.00 END COL2,
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(COL3) = 1 THEN CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),COL3) ELSE 0.00 END COL3
FROM
(
    SELECT '1' AS COL1, '2.05' AS COL2,'52.52' AS COL3 UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL AS COL1, '6' AS COL2, 'NA' AS COL3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'NA' AS COL1, NULL AS COL2, NULL AS COL3 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2' AS COL1, 'NA' AS COL2,'25.63' AS COL3
) X
```

***Note***: When decimal column has bigger value like "123456789.52" than you will get "Arithmetic overflow" error.